# Visual Studio sorts usings in wrong order

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've just discovered what seems to be an annoying bug in Visual Studio 2010. It appears that the Sort Usings function is sorting my usings in the wrong order. Have a look at this code:

```
namespace Test
{
  using Test.WebPages.Utilities;
  using Test.WebPages.WebRef;
  using Test.WebPages.ViewModels;

  namespace WebPages
  {
    namespace Utilities { class A { } }
    namespace WebRef { class B { } }
    namespace ViewModels { class C { } }
  }

  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var a = new A();
      var b = new B();
      var c = new C();
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously the sort order is wrong. Annoying when you're using StyleCop SA1210.

Comment: Works fine on my machine, it reorders them.  VS2010 SP1, en-US.

Comment: Strange, I am using VS2010 SP1, sv-SE though.

Comment: Vell, the Svedes don't like using W much. Check if that's the problem letter.

Comment: It's on my keyboard, along with åäö ;-) I tried namespaces U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Å, Ä, Ö (horrible, I know). Only W comes in the wrong place. I wonder which country has W between U anv V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, now I have some more insight. I tried this:

```
using Test.W; // place W here, initially
using Test.U;
using Test.V;
using Test.X;
using Test.Y;

namespace Test
{
  namespace U { class A { } }
  namespace V { class B { } }
  namespace W { class C { } }
  namespace X { class D { } }
  namespace Y { class E { } }

  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      new A();
      new B();
      new C();
      new D();
      new E();
    }
  }
}
```

Sorting the usings above results in:

```
using Test.U;
using Test.W; // place W here, initially
using Test.V;
using Test.X;
using Test.Y;
```

which is wrong, of course. However, I then tried this order initially:

```
using Test.U;
using Test.V;
using Test.X;
using Test.Y;
using Test.W; // place W here, initially
```

Sorting this resulted in the correct order:

```
using Test.U;
using Test.V;
using Test.W; // place W here, initially
using Test.X;
using Test.Y;
```

Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Sort Usings does anything to usings inside of a namespace

Comment: It doesn't matter if I place them outside of the namespace. When I correct the order manually and then let VS organize them again, they're back to the wrong order.